# How to set focus to cell in Kendo UI for MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to set the focus on a Kendo UI Grid to a specific cell, in the first row during the DataBound event. I'm using Kendo for MVC, here is the definition of my column:

columns.Bound(o => o.QtyCurrentlyReceived).Width(75).Title("Qty Curr Rx");

Comment: Do you mean to put the cell in edit mode? What should focus mean ?

Comment: I suppose to put it in edit mode would probably get the results I'm looking for. the cell is the only one on the Batch Update grid taht is editable and it has a numericTxtBox in it. Right now when the user opens the page, it is not obvious that the cell in question is the one they should be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey then this is the code that should do the work for you:

```
var theCell = $('#Grid tbody td:eq(3)');//sample selector for a cell
$('#Grid').data('tGrid').editCell(theCell);//ask the Grid to put that cell in edit mode
```

Comment: That worked perfectly once I got the names aligned. Not sure why you used tGrid in the second line, I though kendoGrid had to be used but once I changed that it worked perfectly, now my usaes will at least have a clue as to what they are supposed to be eidting. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AlanFisher , its not working for me , the page gets hanged when i tried to put the above code.

`var theCell = $('#Grid tbody td:eq(3)');//sample selector for a cell
$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').editCell(theCell);//ask the Grid to put that cell in edit mode`

can u plz guide me ..