# i want to set focus on grid column in kendo

Tags: jquery, grid, kendo-ui

i am try to check table column value when lost focus from them.
i made one demo to show and good for easy understand.
this is link. http://jsbin.com/oqeral/16/edit

here i am try to check column value if its true then grid refresh or anything else.
but when its false then i want to set focus on last focus-out field.
here is simple jquery. i made in edit time kendo grid.

```
edit: function(e)
                {   
                   $('table').find('tr').mouseover( function(){
                     var row = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
                     var box = $(row).find('input');
                     $(box).focusout(function(e){
                     if($(box).val() == 'Hood')
                     {
                       alert('Its Hood');
                     }
                       else
                       {
                         alert('Not Hood');
                       }
                     });
                   });
                }
```

here is alert value `Hood` then lost focus from the Hood column.
but If `Not Hood` then again focus in on un hood column.
how can i do this. in kendo grid.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'save' event.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-save

so in your case

```
var t = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: {
         data: users,
         pageSize: 10
     },
     pageable: true,
     selectable: "multiple row",
     toolbar: ["create"],
     columns: [{
         field: "UserId"
     }, {
         field: "UserName"
     }, {
         field: "IsAdmin"
     }, {
         command: "destroy",
         title: " ",
         width: "100px"
     }],
     editable: true,
     save: function (e) {

       // here you have the name before edit
       console.log('Name was: '+e.model.UserName);
       // with e.values you have the new values the user gave
       console.log('New name: '+e.values.UserName);

       // if the user has not given 'Hood' as a name for example...
       if(e.values.UserName!=='Hood'){
         // make your check and if you want to prevent saving you can do this for example
         e.preventDefault();
       }
     }
 });
```

Comment: good job. work at somelevel but i want to set editCell() on condition ture.

Comment: here is some i have find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851071/how-to-set-focus-to-cell-in-kendo-ui-for-mvc-grid

Comment: why prompt the user go again in edit mode? You can give him a message and just not allow him to enter a value you don't accept. So you never leave edit mode from this row in the first place. It's faster and simpler. Unless you want something else to do.