# kendo ui grid batch editing, set focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I working on a kendo ui grid. The grid is not-editable as default.
In the toolbar is a 'edit' button. When the user clicks on it, the grid should be editable in batch mode like [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing.html).

The only solution to get this work is remove and recreate the grid/datasource with new properties (editable:true etc).

This works as expected. Now I want to set the focus on the first row/cell, so that the user can see that the grid is editable now (in the example below the row becomes an input field).

Any suggestions for this?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fool/KG23s/) for this.

```
 $('.k-grid-edit').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // remove old grid
     $('#grid').html('');

     // recreate grid with edit: true and new datasource
     $('#grid').kendoGrid({
         dataSource: dataSourceInEdit,
         editable: true,
         columns: [{
             field: 'TableId',
             title: 'Id',
             width: 50
         }, {
             field: 'Area',
             title: 'Area'
         }, {
             field: 'Table',
             title: 'Table',
             width: 60
         }, {
             command: 'destroy',
             title: '&nbsp;',
             width: 100
         }]
    }).data("kendoGrid");

}); // end edit
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your issue? The grid in the link you gave has different behavior!

Comment: @VivekParekh there is one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it:
These 2 lines make it happen:

```
var grid = $("#rt_tableGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.editRow($("#rt_tableGrid tr:eq(1)"));
```

Certainly only on my local script, in the Fiddle I cant´t get it to work.

Although in the Docu is written: Requires "inline" or "popup"
Documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-editRow)

Comment: I need to set the focus on a specific cell in the selected row? How can I do that? Can you please help?

Comment: does this not work? For me it selects a specific cell, 
grid.editRow($('#rtGridEdit tr:eq(' + index + ')'));

Comment: Couldn't use your code, do you mean I have to specify the index manually?

Comment: 1=firstCell, 2=secondCell, ... what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Index seems to be pointing to row rather than cell. if there is only one row in my grid & if I put 3 for index the code is not running. but if I put 1 for index, its focusing to the only/first row's first cell.

Comment: ah ok, youre right. have you seens this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851071/how-to-set-focus-to-cell-in-kendo-ui-for-mvc-grid

Comment: I had seen that, may be it would be better to ask a new question. Thanks anyway.